# Can Ant properties resolve other properties?

Tags: ant, properties

Can Ant properties set via properties file, resolve other properties from properties files?

For example, I can do this:

```
<property name="prop1" value="in_test_xml1" />
<property name="prop2" value="${prop1}" />
```

and prop2 becomes "in_test_xml1". That's good.

But in this case, when using an input properties file:

```
prop1=sample_prop
prop2=${prop1}
```

prop2 is not set to "sample_prop"

So resolving properties from other properties only seems to work when the property doing the resolving is in the ant file itself.

Is this expected or am i missing something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ant does support in-file property expansion, see the Property File section in the manual for the [Property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task.

The following example shows properties getting resolved:

- within a single properties file
- from one properties file in another properties file
- within a build file

First properties file:

```
$ cat props1.properties
prop1=world
prop2=hello ${prop1}
```

Second properties file:

```
$ cat props2.properties
prop3=goodbye ${prop1}
```

Build file:

```
<project default="test">
  <property file="props1.properties"/>
  <property file="props2.properties"/>
  <property name="prop4" value="${prop3}, good luck"/>
  <target name="test">
    <echo message="prop1 = ${prop1}"/>
    <echo message="prop2 = ${prop2}"/>
    <echo message="prop3 = ${prop3}"/>
    <echo message="prop4 = ${prop4}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Output:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

test:
     [echo] prop1 = world
     [echo] prop2 = hello world
     [echo] prop3 = goodbye world
     [echo] prop4 = goodbye world, good luck

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Is there another kind of property resolution that is not working for you?

**Edit**

Following your comment, I now understand that you are using the `-propertyfile` command line option to specify a property file for Ant to load (rather than specifying the file in the buildfile itself, as I did above).

I did quick test with this and find that Ant 1.7.1 did not do in-file property expansion on files loaded using that command line option. But Ant 1.8.2 does.

This is Ant [Bug 18732](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18732). You should be able to resolve by updating your version of Ant.

Comment: i was importing properties from a propertyfile via command line. in that case, i do not see the properties getting expanded.

Comment: OK, so you are using the `-propertyfile` command line option. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ewan.chalmers From local testing with ANT 1.8.4, it does not appear that this works on the command line, where one property references another. E.g. `ant -Dprop1=world '-Dprop2=hello ${prop1}' test`

Comment: @ptha I'm not using Ant for years now, so over to you :)

Answer (score 6):

A simpler solution for this task would be the usage of *Ant-contrib Tasks: Propertycopy*.

From the [manual](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertycopy.html):

```
<property name="org" value="MyOrg" />
<property name="org.MyOrg.DisplayName" value="My Organiziation" />
<propertycopy name="displayName" from="org.${org}.DisplayName" />

Sets displayName to "My Organiziation".
```