# Ant property file reference another property file

Tags: ant

I have an ant build that has a main build.properties file.  One of the projects that is built has a their own property file.  I am wondering if it is possible to reference one of the properties defined in the main file in the secondary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, assuming that the buildfile of the sub project loads the main build.properties file, and does so before it loads its own properties file.

If both of those are true, then the properties file in the sub project can reference properties from the main build.properties.

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267113/can-ant-properties-resolve-other-properties/6267574#6267574).